# Umschreibung von »er ist weg«

Tags: synonym

Der Satz lautet so:

> Man kann auf Facebook jeden Nutzer melden, der einem zweifelhaft vorkommt, und in Kürze **ist er weg**.

Dabei scheint der letzte Teil des Satzes nicht ganz richtig zu sein. Wie kann man das umschreiben, sodass es etwas "knackiger" wird?

Comment: Was erscheint Dir daran nicht ganz richtig? Es gibt zwar unzählige Alternativen (flugs wird er verbannt, rasch wird er entfernt, bald ist er Geschichte, schon ist er weg/fort/raus, ...) aber knackiger?

Comment: @userunknown Mein Deutschlehrer hat den Satz damals mit einem "~A", also "Ausdrucksfehler" am Rande versehen, daher dachte ich, dass "weg sein" in solchem Kontext nicht angemessen ist

Comment: Es ist halt sehr flapsig, aber falsch ist es nicht. Ich denke, der Deutschlehrer hätte da lieber so etwas wie "und in Kürze ist der Account gelöscht/gesperrt" oder so ähnlich gelesen.

Comment: "der Datenkrake entronnen"?

Comment: "knackiger" und "vom Deutschlehrer bemängelt" scheinen mir 2 unterschiedliche, womöglich konfligierende Aspekte zu sein. Vielleicht fehlte dem Lehrer das Futur ("in Kürze wird er weg sein")? Mich irritiert der Inhalt der Behauptung - zweifelhafte Nutzer werden auf Zuruf gelöscht, bei Facebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich hätte vermutlich so etwas geschrieben wie

> ... und innerhalb kurzer Zeit wird sein Accout geprüft und gegebenenfalls gelöscht.

Deine Formulierung - wenn auch nicht unbedingt falsch - klingt sehr umgangssprachlich, zumal nicht der Nutzer selbst "weg" ist, sondern nur dessen Konto.

Comment: Inhaltlich gibt das "ist er weg" weder eine Prüfung her, noch ein "gegebenenfalls". Inhaltlich ist Dein Satz zwar sicher näher an der Realität, aber in sprachlicher Hinsicht ist er deswegen gerade kein Äquivalent. Womöglich steht der Satz in einem Kontext, in dem wichtig ist, dass die Aussage falsch ist.